# Node+express can't access static files

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am using the following code to get the static files which are all residing in a folder called public but I keep on getting 404s on all the references, where am I going wrong?

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
```

Then, I am referencing my files in the following way:

```
<script src='/js/nprogress.js'></script>
<link rel='stylesheet' href='/css/nprogress.css'/>
<link href="/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/styles.css">
<script src="/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

I am referencing the files in layouts/main.handlebars.

The folder structure is as follows: 
[image]

Comment: what's the url that appears in the 404 in the browser console?

Comment: @yBrodsky http://www.example.com/js/common.js  and so on

Comment: Go and manually put the right url in the browser. Like: `localhost:3000/js/common.js` I think the problem is your trailing `/` in your script and link tags

Comment: @yBrodsky   surprisingly, localhost works but not when I push it to my domain

Comment: remove the trailing slash from your href. `href="/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css"` => `href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css"`

Comment: @yBrodsky actually the problem was something totally different, on the page that is supposed to run this, I forgot to mention the port number x_x! added :3000 and worked like a charm :)